# What are branches in BitBucket and how to manage them

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I have the following problem. I have a repo, which I originally cloned from github using hg-git, but since I've been developing on it in mercurial. The original dev also keeps updating the repo, so we have multiple heads and I merge whatever I want using TortoiseHg, it works really well (I think hg-git doesn't make a difference here). However I have the following problem: now I've pushed my version to BitBucket, and it has three branches.

[image: 3 default]

I'm totally confused with this. Shouldn't a branch in git be a bookmark in Hg? Then why does BitBucket support branches and not bookmarks? I really don't get what is a branch in Hg and why do I have 3, when actually `hg branch` only lists one: `default`? Or they are actually not branches, but bookmarks, just BitBucket named them like this not to confuse git users? But this is a Hg repo (set to be Hg when I created initially), and I'm not using git!

When I try `hg heads -q` I get the exact same result:

```
235:03d08bcf3144
233:d7fbd581b9e1
227:abda0dc38b93
```

So is it actually a head what BitBucket calles a branch? Is so, how can I name them like branches in Git, like default, forked-from, etc.?

One idea I had in mind was to create a bookmark at each head. I figured out how to `push -B` each of them to BitBucket. Now it looks like this:

[image: 6 branch]

So now it starts to make sense, but what can I do with the 3 defaults? Why are they there and what are they actually? Branches, heads or bookmarks in Hg?

And why do I have only one in BitBucket settings?

[image: 1 in settings]

Answer (score 1):

You have three heads in single **named** branch "default" and these three heads **are branches** - **anonymous** branches

If you want to eliminate these branches inside "default" you have just merge heads (two heads - own line and pulled from upstream: I don't know without history, how you get third) in local repository before push to BitBucket

Comment: Third was just because the developer used two different repos. My problem is that I don't want to use named branches for branching, but just bookmarks.

In the meanwhile I fixed it in the following way:
1. Most importantly I realized that my problem is that Mercurial pushes **all** branches by default. I fixed it with `push --rev .` or TortoiseHg's `defaultpush = revision`.
2. For fixing the actual repo, I closed down the heads with `--close-branch`, pushed to bitbucket and `hg strip`-ed local
3. Now a single-branch push fixed it

The way bitbucket UI handles this is still very confusing.

Comment: The point is that these are proper (anonymous) branches and should not be merged before pushing to bitbucket. The handling of bookmarks on bitbucket is just not very complete (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

You probably already read [A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/). That is good overview over the different "kinds of mercurial branches".

So git branches are normally translated to hg bookmarks. That is you keep using one hg repository with one (un-)named branch "default". On this default branch you have one bookmark for every "git branch".

Now the problem with bitbucket is, that its "hg bookmark" support (currently) isn't as complete as "git branch" support.

So at the time of your writing they didn't have bookmark support at all and just had support for (anonymous) heads. Most bookmarks are also heads, so you can see one hash for every head/bookmark. However, some bookmarks are not on a head, but all of their commits are included in another bookmark/head. These were completely invisible on bitbucket.

As of now, bookmarks are displayed (with their name) in the commits view and can be selected in the drop down.
They are not displayed in the "branch" tab.
It also isn't possible in general to open pull requests for bookmarks.
However, for bookmarks that are heads, you can open a pull request for that head.

See also: [bitbucket issue: can't create pull request from hg bookmark](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6705/cant-create-pull-request-from-hg-bookmark)